# Is JPA's flush and JDBC Batch works as same internally?

Tags: jpa, jdbc

As per my understanding flush() method of JPA's entitymanager will sync the data available in persistence context with Database in a single DB network call. Thus it avoids multiple DB calls when somebody trying to persist large amount of records. Why can't I consider this as a batch equivalent (I know flush() may not be implemented for that purpose) of JDBC batch insert ? Because, JDBC batch insert also work with the same idea that it make only single DB call for all the statements it added to the statement object ?

From a performance point of view, both are comparable ? Are they work with the same technique ? Internally, at Database side both will generate same number of queries ?

Somebody please make me understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> entitymanager will sync the data available in persistence context with Database in a single DB network call

No, not at all. That isn't possible. A flush could possibly delete from several tables, insert in several tables, and update several tables. That can't be done in a single network call.

A flush *can* use batch statements to execute multiple similar inserts or updates though.

Comment: I know all other pending operations will get synced upon flush execution. I wanted to know only in the context of bulk insert into same table. There JDBC batch and JPA's flush work with same strategy that JPA's flush will also work like batch insert(That is single DB call or multiple DB call) ? Is there a huge difference in terms of performance ?

Comment: A flush will use batch statements if you have configured your JPA engine to use batch statements, of if it's the default configuration of the JPA engine to use batch statements.